# erro metodo GET ao consumir WebApi

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Criei um projeto em AspNet WebApi, adicionei um ADO(DataBase-first) para se conectar com o banco Mysql e criei o controller usando a opção **'Controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework'**, quando faço o teste em uma tabela que não tem relacionamentos(Chave estrangeira) consigo fazer todos as operacões (GET,POST,PUT, DELETE) sem problemas, porem, quando utilizo uma tabela que tem algum relacionamento, os métodos que utilizam GET trazem os erros:

```
{
   "Message": "Ocorreu um erro.",
   "ExceptionMessage": "O tipo 'ObjectContent`1' não pôde serializar o corpo da resposta para o tipo de conteúdo 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.",
   "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
   "StackTrace": null,
   "InnerException":    {
      "Message": "Ocorreu um erro.",
      "ExceptionMessage": "Error getting value from 'categoria1' on 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.categoria_AFADBC1AC82DEC74C8DC54EEEDBFC75EBDE4C72DE1B441D01DF364DCB962FD70'.",
      "ExceptionType": "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException",
      "StackTrace": "   em Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)\r\n   em Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)\r\n   em Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   em Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   em Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   em Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   em Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   em Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   em System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   em System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   em System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)\r\n   em System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n   em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   em System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()",
      "InnerException":       {
         "Message": "Ocorreu um erro.",
         "ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.",
         "ExceptionType": "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException",
         "StackTrace": "   em System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)\r\n   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()\r\n   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()\r\n   em System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.Execute(MergeOption mergeOption)\r\n   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(List`1 collection, MergeOption mergeOption)\r\n   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(MergeOption mergeOption)\r\n   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad()\r\n   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.LoadProperty[TItem](TItem propertyValue, String relationshipName, String targetRoleName, Boolean mustBeNull, Object wrapperObject)\r\n   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.<GetInterceptorDelegate>b__1(TProxy proxy, TItem item)\r\n   em System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.categoria_AFADBC1AC82DEC74C8DC54EEEDBFC75EBDE4C72DE1B441D01DF364DCB962FD70.get_categoria1()\r\n   em Getcategoria1(Object )\r\n   em Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)",
         "InnerException":          {
            "Message": "Ocorreu um erro.",
            "ExceptionMessage": "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.",
            "ExceptionType": "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException",
            "StackTrace": "   em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception exception)\r\n   em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Throw(Exception ex)\r\n   em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.CheckState()\r\n   em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   em MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   em System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   em System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)\r\n   em System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)\r\n   em System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)\r\n   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   em System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   em System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

A classe criada pelo database-first é:

```
namespace take5.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class categoria
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public categoria()
        {
            this.categoria1 = new HashSet<categoria>();
            this.produto_categoria = new HashSet<produto_categoria>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string descricao { get; set; }
        public int categoria_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> filial_id { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<categoria> categoria1 { get; set; }
        public virtual categoria categoria2 { get; set; }
        public virtual filial filial { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<produto_categoria> produto_categoria { get; set; }
    }
}
```

e o controller é:

```
namespace take5.Controllers
{
    public class categoriasController : ApiController
    {
        private MeuContexto db = new MeuContexto();

        // GET: api/categorias
        public IQueryable<categoria> Getcategoria()
        {
            return db.categoria;
        }

        // GET: api/categorias/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(categoria))]
        public IHttpActionResult Getcategoria(int id)
        {
            categoria categoria = db.categoria.Find(id);
            if (categoria == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(categoria);
        }

        // PUT: api/categorias/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public IHttpActionResult Putcategoria(int id, categoria categoria)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != categoria.id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(categoria).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!categoriaExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        // POST: api/categorias
        [ResponseType(typeof(categoria))]
        public IHttpActionResult Postcategoria(categoria categoria)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.categoria.Add(categoria);

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                if (categoriaExists(categoria.id))
                {
                    return Conflict();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = categoria.id }, categoria);
        }

        // DELETE: api/categorias/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(categoria))]
        public IHttpActionResult Deletecategoria(int id)
        {
            categoria categoria = db.categoria.Find(id);
            if (categoria == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.categoria.Remove(categoria);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(categoria);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool categoriaExists(int id)
        {
            return db.categoria.Count(e => e.id == id) > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Alguém tem idéia porque isso acontece?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema acrescentando [JsonIgnore] na virtual property de cada campo que eu queria que ignorasse:

```
[JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<categoria> categoria1 { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual categoria categoria2 { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual filial filial { get; set; }
         [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<produto_categoria> produto_categoria { get; set; }
```

encontrei essa solução no site [https://forums.asp.net/t/2057281.aspx?The+ObjectContent+1+type+failed+to+serialize+the+response+body+for+content+type+application+json+charset+utf+8+](https://forums.asp.net/t/2057281.aspx?The%20ObjectContent%201%20type%20failed%20to%20serialize%20the%20response%20body%20for%20content%20type%20application%20json%20charset%20utf%208%20), depois disso o json funciona blz com o GET.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que isso ocorra pois a propriedade `categoria1` é do mesmo tipo da classe em questão.

Tente adicionar na classe o atributo abaixo :

```
[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]
```

Comment: Bom dia @Rodolpho, diz como você indicou, porém, o erro continua o mesmo. Ficou :`[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]
    public partial class categoria`